# c# loop and sum data

Tags: c#, image

I have image_1 in PictureBox1. I want to scan through a rectangular section in the middle of this image, say about 300 to 500 on the x-axis and 300 to 450 on the y-axis. When I scan through this section I want to add up the values of all the pixels and get an average value for them.

I then have image_2 in PictureBox2, the test image. This is a copy of the first image but the PictureBox2 has a scroll bar on it. If I then scan through the second image at the same locations as I did with the first image, sum every pixel value within that rectangle and get an average of them the values should be exactly the same as the value I got with image_1.

Now, I will move image_2 with the scroll bar on PictureBox2 slightly up in the vertical, y-axis, and redo the scan in the same fixed locations as previously, add up the pixel values and get their average. These values should be different because I am scanning a different section of the image.
I then repeat this process some more with varying degrees of difference in the y-axis on image_2 to get value readings.

This is to prove a concept only. That scanning the images at a fixed rectangular location, summing and averaging values is enough to eventually narrow down the values so that the beginning of an object can be located.

Whether this is thought to be possible or not I would like to attempt it.
Please advise the simplest method. It is not necessary at this stage to attempt the fastest or most efficient method, purely the simplest is best at present

Is it something I can simply do like this?

```
namespace imageAlign
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap myImage1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd1.FileName);

                        // get pixel value and store it in array, sum and average it so it can Be compared to image2
                int sum = 0;
                         for (int i = 0; i > 300 && i < 500; i++)
                         {
                             for (int j = 0; j > 300 && j < 450; i++)
                            {
                                int[] img1 = new int[i];
                                sum += img1[i];
                                MessageBox.Show(sum);
                                 //Color pixel = img1.GetPixel(i,j);
                                 //sum and average pixel values in array
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What is the goal of all this. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to know by how much the second image has been scrolled by comparing it to the first one? Can it be scrolled both, horizontally and vertically?

Comment: your for loops are incorrect. if you want to go from 300 to 500 in i, should be __for(int i = 300; i<500; i++);__  What you have written will fall right out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Your conception on the way for loops work is wrong. This loop will never loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i > 300 && i < 500; i++) ...
```

Since `i` is `0` at the beginning, the condition `i > 300` is not met and the loop will not even start to loop. Write this instead:

```
 for (int i = 300; i < 500; i++) ...
```

---

I assume that you try to find by how much the second image has been scrolled, by comparing it to the first (non scrolled) image. (You are talking about a solution to a problem that you didn't explain.)

Why working with an average? This will be very expensive, because you will have to calculate the average of tens of thousands of pixels for every possible position.

First we need to know how the scrolling happens. Only horizontally, or only vertically, or both? This will influence the algorithm.

If both images are exactly the same, I would compare single pixels only, and if you found a matching pixel, compare the pixels next to it until either all available pixels match or you detect a difference.

Here is a rough sketch of the algorithm I have in mind (in pseudo code):

```
for every x in image1 up to image1.width - pattern.width
    for every y in image1 up to image1.height - pattern.height
        if match_found(x, y) then
            return x, y      -- this is the desired result
        end if                
    next
next
if we reach this point, we didn't find a match.

function match_found(x, y)
    for every xp in pattern     -- where pattern is a portion of image 2
        for every yp in pattern
            if image1[x + xp, y + yp] not equal pattern[xp, yp]
               return false
        next
    next
    return true
end function
```

You could also try to adapt algorithms that were developed for searching string patterns, like the Boyer-Moore algorithm, to this image problem. Basically Boyer-Moore tries to skip as many positions as possible if no match is found, by using a distance table. See [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) on Wikipedia..